# Upgrade kitchen gfci outlets - wiring question

Tags: electrical

We are redoing our old kitchen and  I have the chance to upgrade the two light switches to a switch and gfci outlet. The two lights have the incoming power so the switches are at the end.
However there is a line coming up from the oven counter area I can extend as power for the 2 gfci outlets.
My question is if the current switch locations are close enough or if it doesn’t matter bc it’s an old kitchen and won’t need to be up to code.

[image: light switch locations]

[image: light switches and line to feed outlets]

Comment: Can you get us information on the dimensions of the boxes involved and photos of their innards?

Comment: Why do you want to update light fixtures to GFCI? Hard wired light fixtures are not required to be GFCI protected. Even in a garage/ bathroom where all receptacles do require GFCI protection.

Comment: The switch box is a single gang box.

Comment: I want to add a gfci outlet and light switch combo so that I can have outlets on that wall. A combo like this one https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-15-Amp-125-Volt-Combo-Self-Test-Tamper-Resistant-GFCI-Outlet-and-Switch-White-R92-GFSW1-0KW/206000203

Comment: I've not seen a response so I've paid an electrician to do this.